# Does Catalyst make $c globally available?

Tags: fastcgi, catalyst

Is there anyway to get access to `$c` without passing it around? I've got a third party library that runs through `CGI::Application` that I bootstrap with `Catalyst::Controller::WrapCGI`. What's the best way to get `$c` into the code being called so I can prepare to migrate it to Catalyst?

If it doesn't make it accessible, how do I get access to `$c` in an application context?

Answer (score 2):

### No

At least as far as I can tell, but [this blog entry in the Catalyst Advent Calendar](http://www.catalystframework.org/calendar/2014/20) gives you an idea of how to accomplish it. They just make a global and an accessor, and if it works.. it works?

```
our $__ACTIVE_CTX;
sub ctx { $__ACTIVE_CTX }

around 'dispatch' => sub {
  my ($orig, $c, @args) = @_;
  local $__ACTIVE_CTX = $c;
  $c->$orig(@args)
};
```

But, before you roll your own, check out this module [`CatalystX::GlobalContext`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CatalystX::GlobalContext) which solves just this problem. Copied from synopsis:

```
package MyApp::Controller::Root;

use CatalystX::GlobalContext ();

sub auto : Private {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    CatalystX::GlobalContext->set_context($c);
    1;
}

package Some::Other::Module;

use CatalystX::GlobalContext '$c';

...
do stuff with $c
...
```